# method invocation order with java object reference

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

As my previous question [Java method invocation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633171/java-method-invocation-order)

If my code changes

```
public class MyClassTest {

    private static MyClass m = new MyClass(10);

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m.initMe(getint());
    }

    public static int getint() {
        m = new MyClass(20);
        return 40;
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private int i;

    public MyClass(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    void initMe(int i) {
        System.out.println(this.i);
    }
}
```

My output is 10 not 20 causing Java is pass-by-value right?
So It also matters that method invocation order also affected by object reference align with runtime type.

Comment: What in hell are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

`m.initMe(getint());` it instructs to call the method of Object which refered by m.

Now if m refer a new object in between of execution though instruction will definatly call the old object's method. And once it is done Object will be unreachable and will also be garbaged collected.

Answer (score 0):

You see, here you create a new `MyClass` with a value of 10:

```
private static MyClass m = new MyClass(10);
```

now, `this.i` is `10`, because, well, you said it should be `10`.

The reason it does not return `20` is because when you call:

```
m.initMe(getint());
```

it will return `10` because it was the value assigned to `m` at the time of the `initMe()` call.

---

If you do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        m = new MyClass(20);
        m.initMe(getint());
    }

    public static int getint() {
        return 40;
    }
```

you get:
`20`, because NOW you've assigned a value of `20` to your object BEFORE execution of `initMe()`.

---

Interestingly enough, if you do this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        m.initMe(getint());
        m.initMe(getint());
    }

    public static int getint() {
        m = new MyClass(20);
        return 40;
    }
```

you get:

```
10
20
```

because at the first run, the value would be `10`, but `m` was assigned a value of `20` now, and for the next run, BEFORE execution, it will hold a value of `20`.

Answer (score 0):

How you answered the previous question, the JVM is a stack-based machine. First run the static section where are initialized instance of MyClass(10). After this, `main()` are executed, where instance of MyClass(10) will be pushed to the operand stack(`0: getstatic     #2`). After this, `getint()` will be executed, where new instance of MyClass(20) will be created (`6: invokespecial #6`) and set new static field (`9: putstatic #2`), But in the **operand stack** is still the old value ( MyClass(10) ).

```
static {};
 Code:
   0: new           #5                  // class MyClass
   3: dup
   4: bipush        10
   6: invokespecial #6                  // Method MyClass."<init>":(I)V
   9: putstatic     #2                  // Field m:LMyClass;
  12: return
LineNumberTable:
  line 3: 0

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0: getstatic     #2                  // Field m:LMyClass;
   3: invokestatic  #3                  // Method getint:()I
   6: invokevirtual #4                  // Method MyClass.initMe:(I)V
   9: return
  LineNumberTable:
  line 7: 0
  line 8: 9

public static int getint();
  Code:
    0: new           #5                  // class MyClass
    3: dup
    4: bipush        20
    6: invokespecial #6                  // Method MyClass."<init>":(I)V
    9: putstatic     #2                  // Field m:LMyClass;
   12: bipush        40
   14: ireturn
  LineNumberTable:
   line 11: 0
   line 12: 12
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what happens when the below line is executed.

```
m.initMe(getint());
```

`m` which is referring to the object containing `10` value is used to call the `initMe()` method. Now post the invocation of `initMe()`, you make `m` refer a new object reference in the `getint()` method.

But since the `initMe()` was called prior to the new assignment, the `this.i` returns `10` instead of `20`.

After this point, `m` refers the new object which has the `i` value as `20`. If you add another line `m.initMe(getint());` after the first statement, you'll get *20* from the second statement execution.

---

> So It also matters that method invocation order also affected by
>   object reference align with runtime type

Thus, the answer is *Yes*, the order does matter.